# finding neighborhood in a specific location

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I have a 2D matrix and I want to find the neighborhood of (i,j) in this matrix with M and N sizes in x and y directions, respectively. I know that it is easy to do, but my problem is that when (i,j) is close to corners and M and N are large! In this case I do not want to exceed the matrix. Is there any function or simple solution for this problem in MATLAB?

Comment: What do you mean by 'find neighborhood'? Do you want to extract sub-matrices (e.g. 3x3 matrix around entry (i,j)), or do you want to perform some computations on the neighborhood, e.g. some filter? Try to be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to extract a submatrix from a matrix, with the submatrix centered going from row `i-M` to `i+M` and column `j-N` to `j+N`.

If this is the case and you would like to avoid selecting invalid indices, you can chop the selection using min/max functions, eg:

```
matrix = randi(10,20,15);
siz = size(matrix);

i=2;
j=5;
M=10;
N=3;

selectrows = max(1,i-M):min(siz(1),i+M);
selectcols = max(1,j-N):min(siz(2),j+N);
result = matrix(selectrows, selectcols);
```