# Indexes and values of surrounding cells in 3d matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'd like to return the indexes and values of the 8 cells surrounding a cell in a 3d matrix.

```
mat = rand(5,5,5);

% Cell of interest
pos = [3 3 3]
pos_val = mat(pos(1), pos(2), pos(3))

% Surrounding cells
surrounding_pos = [pos(1)-1:pos(1)+1; pos(2)-1:pos(2)+1; pos(2)-1:pos(2)+1]
surrounding_val = mat(surrounding_pos(1,:), surrounding_pos(2,:), surrounding_pos(3,:))
```

This works fine for values in the centre of a matrix, but it breaks if pos is on the edge. (E.g. if pos was `[3,4,5]`, surrounding_pos would include `[3,4,6]`, which is out of bounds)

I could obviously remove surrounding_pos values <0 or >size(mat), but this doesn't seem like a terribly MATLABian method. Any ideas?

Comment: Depending on your problem, a workaround could be to pad your matrix with NaNs on all sides. Then your indexing works fine and you only have to care about ignoring the NaNs in your analysis.

Comment: you can use the same approach as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419772/finding-neighborhood-in-a-specific-location/12419908#12419908

Comment: @H.Muster Good idea, but I'd like to explore just getting the relevant indexes instead of manipulating the whole matrix - performance is important

Comment: @Alex:This is why I wrote "depending on your problem". If you going to query on one and the same matrix over and over again, the padding approach might result in a better performance. If you do only few queries on many different matrices, its performance might be inferior.

Comment: I concur completely with @H.Muster - padding the array with a halo containing an identity element for the operation on the stencil of cells is generally much more performant for this type of operation when the operation count rises.

Comment: How big is your target grid and how many cells are of interest? and how many times? @H.Muster is right in that it might be beneficial to change your data structure depending on what you want to do.

Comment: In my situation I'm accessing a lot of different matrices only once - I don't want to have to pad them all individually to access the contents. Thanks for all the advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a tidied up version. Cheers.

```
mat = rand(5,5,5);
N = size(mat)
if length(N) < 3 || length(N) > 3; error('Input must be 3 dimensional'); end;
pos = [1 3 5]
surrounding_val = mat(max(pos(1)-1, 1):min(pos(1)+1, N(1)), max(pos(2)-1, 1):min(pos(2)+1, N(2)), max(pos(3)-1, 1):min(pos(3)+1, N(3)))
```

**EDIT**: Added an error trap.

Comment: Since it's not guaranteed to be square, one could also do v = size(mat), then v(1), v(2) in the place of N

Comment: The error trap only kicks into action if you have a `NxNx1xNx...` matrix; singleton dimensions at highest dimension are automatically not displayed (nor returned by `size`). (Because in theory every matrix is a `NxNx1x1x...` matrix.)

Comment: @GuntherStruyf You are correct. Sorry, I'm not doing very well today am I? :-) I've fixed the error trap.

Answer (score 5):

Same solution as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419772/finding-neighborhood-in-a-specific-location/12419908#12419908), but extended to multiple (any) dimensions:

```
mat = randi(10,5,5,5);
siz = size(mat );
N = numel(siz); % number of dimensions
M = 1; % surrounding region size

pos = [3 3 3];
pos_val = mat(pos(1), pos(2), pos(3));

surrounding_pos = cell(N,1);
for ii=1:N
    surrounding_pos{ii} = max(1,pos(ii)-M):min(siz(ii),pos(ii)+M);
end
surrounding_val2 = mat(surrounding_pos{:});
```

The important part is the last four lines, it avoids having to c/p the max, min thing for every dimension..

Or if you like short code, the loop changed to an `arrayfun`:

```
surrounding_pos = arrayfun(@(ii) max(1,pos(ii)-M):min(siz(ii),pos(ii)+M), 1:N,'uni',false);
surrounding_val2 = mat(surrounding_pos{:});
```

Comment: Neat extension - well worth a +1. And now this thread definitely isn't a duplicate of the link you provided :-)

Comment: started typing when you posted you couldn't figure it out.. it covers the same content anyway

Answer (score 0):

I found this post because I needed to grab the surrounding indices of a chosen point in a Matrix.  It seems like the answers here are returning a matrix of the surrounding values, but the question is also interested in the surrounding indices.  I was able to do this with "try/catch" statements, which I previously did not know existed in MATLAB.  For a 2D Matrix, Z:

```
%Select a node in the matrix
Current = Start_Node;

%Grab its x, y, values (these feel reversed for me...)
C_x = rem(Start_Node, length(Z));
if C_x ==0
    C_x =length(Z);
end
C_y = ceil(Start_Node/length(Z));
C_C = [C_x, C_y];

%Grab the node's surrounding nodes.
try
    TRY = Z(C_x - 1, C_y);
    Top = Current -1;
catch
    Top = Inf;
end
try
    TRY = Z(C_x + 1, C_y);
    Bottom = Current +1;
catch
    Bottom = Inf;
end
try
    TRY = Z(C_x, C_y + 1);
    Right = Current + length(Z);
catch
    Right = Inf;
end
try
    TRY = Z(C_x, C_y - 1);
    Left = Current - length(Z);
catch
    Left = Inf;
end

surround = [Top, Bottom, Left, Right];
m = numel(surround == inf);
k = 1;
%Eliminate infinites.

surround(surround==inf) =[];
```

I hope someone finds this information relevant.

Comment: Ugh, not sure why the formatting comes out so horribly.  Sorry, don't know how to fix.